# javascript syntax structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, modal-dialog

I am trying to understand this snippet of code and was hoping I could get some assistance.

the purpose it to use an onclick event to open a bootstrap modal and I have it working but I want to pass in the modal I want to active when I call the script

```
    function showThisModal() {
       $(#usage).modal('show'); 
    }
```

the function on first glance is quite simple it displays the modal I have setup with the id of usage. the part that is throwing me is the '#' in front of the modal name

```
    function showThisModal(modID) {
       $(modID).modal('show');  
    }
```

doesn't seem to work if I pass in the modal name ---usage---  or if I pass in the modal name with a # in front of it ---#usage---

What is the significance of the '#' and how do I set this function up to pass in the modal name

like so

```
onclick='showThisModal($modal)'
```

where $modal is any modal name I have available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The # refers to an id set in the html. so (it looks like you are using jQuery) `$('#usage')` selects the element with the id of usage. In your function passing in modID you need it to be a string with the hash. In the onclick, where you have $modal you would really want the id, so this.id should do that I think.

edit: so your html would be like `<button id="modalWanted" onclick="showThisModal(this.id)">`